# Missing vault and information check

Tags: lotus-notes

(I'm interested to know what/how to do in Lotus Notes when setting a new password of a user that says:

*"User's ID has not been uploaded to Notes ID vault"*

---

Then I have another ailment ...

I created a new user according to the formalities (all correct).  When the person to be checked for information, the following message appears:

*"Some documents did not pass the check. See the conflicting users view for more information."*

The user Dane Mooney has an AD-account and Exchange but doesn't exist in Lotus Notes. I can't find Another user with same name/username or ID.

I've tried to change the name of dmooney to damooney without result. Tried to put the mail server on sedom01(for Sweden) insead of audom01(for Australia), even replaced mail file template, certificate, but nothing works. Tried a several of different usernames.

I noticed the path never showed up: *“\Seume-mta300.forest.local\Ds$\ People\ userid\au\dmooney.id”*, but the ID-file does already exist there. Could there be a problem with this? First it was just Dmooney.id without path.

Comment: Hi Evelina, welcome to Super User! Please, try to avoid asking multiple questions in a single post, since it could lead to confussion, as explained [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts).